# SVG icon for google maps markers

Tags: google-maps, ionic3, native, marker

I'm trying to leverage SVG for icons with Ionic Native Maps with the following code:

```
this.map.addMarker({
  icon: {
    path: '...',
    scale: 1.0
  },
  position: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude },
  title: name,
  draggable: true,
  name: name
});
```

But the SVG isn't used...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the question? How to use a SVG as marker? Or why isn't the SVG showing?

Comment: It seems that svg isn't supported for markers with the google maps cordova module...

Answer (score 0):

Ionic Native Maps does not support currently SVG icons as you can see [here](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/1361).

On the other hand you could try to convert the SVG to PNG like this:

```
var svg  = document.getElementById('graph'),
    xml  = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg),
    data = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(xml),
    img  = new Image()

img.setAttribute('src', data)
document.body.appendChild(img)
```

Referenced from this [github](https://gist.github.com/gustavohenke/9073132).

Hope this solves your issue.